# how can I find same pattern among strings?

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to extract the same pattern from strings, say

```
a <- "abczzzzz"
b <- "rrrrabckkk"
```

I would like to get the result of "abc", like

```
somefunction(a,b)
> "abc"
```

have checked `stringr` package, however, these functions are all requiring known pattern which I don't have, and it's impossible to know the nchar of the pattern, so, I prefer the longest matching pattern.
Please advise, thanks.

UPDATE---

In fact, I am handling a massive dataset which is like I only have the descriptions of the sensors, and wanna find out the machine name where it belongs, while the machine name will be the most frequent word in the description. Letter by letter comparison is workable, and I am still looking for more efficient way. Thanks! The answer is already helping me much move forward.

Comment: break up and compare the elements! thanks, will try now!

Comment: That also helps. I will remove the question later.  However, I am always curious, how experienced ppl like you are, can find the duplication or right answers at such a short time? I would say, ur sys.time is 0.001 sec.

Comment: No, it's actually because we spend lot of time here. So we get an idea as soon as we read the question whether the question is duplicate or not and what are the right keywords to search for the duplicate.

Comment: thanks for the honest and sincere feedback. Truly inspired. Will remove the question later once I absorb it. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure this is a (clear) duplicate. Better if you don't delete in case it stays open, or for others to find in the future as a link to the dupe if it gets closed.

Comment: Turns out, it isn't an exact duplicate. Hence, posting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the strings at each character and use `intersect` to get the common ones.

```
intersect(strsplit(a, "")[[1]], strsplit(b, "")[[1]])
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

To get the exact output as requested we can `paste` them together.

```
paste(intersect(strsplit(a, "")[[1]], strsplit(b, "")[[1]]), collapse = "")
#[1] "abc"
```

---

If there are multiple strings we can use `Reduce` (also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822064/extracting-common-characters-from-multiple-vectors-of-different-lengths)):

```
a <- "abczzzzz"
b <- "rrrrabckkk"
c <- "dsaqwabc"

paste(Reduce(intersect, strsplit(c(a, b, c), "")), collapse = "")
#[1] "abc"
```